# i am developing a website with Ruby on Rails, mongoDB , JSON on a Linux. is there going to be any platform based issues for windows/Mac users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, linux, mongodb

i am developing a website which is going to use Ruby on Rails alongwith mongoDB and JSON on a Linux based platform. should i be worried for Windows/Mac users? what steps should i take to avoid any platform issues ?

Comment: Is your question about the server side (i.e. running your app on a windows server) or client side(people using using different browsers to access your site)?

Comment: actually both. please help.i am clueless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And the CSS is compatible with IE7 and IE8.  For a web developer, the platform of deployment most certainly will not affect your users.  Its always the platform of your user that matters.

Answer (score 1):

No just make sure any javascript is compatible with IE7.